# Sending data from JQuery to C#, ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a canvas in my .aspx form page where one can sign a signature, I would like to send the base64 data from the JQuery client side to the C# Asp.Net side. Here I want to upload this base64 data to a database.

(a couple things I tried)
Jquery:

```
$("#savebtn").bind("click", function () {
    var base64 = $('#sketch')[0].toDataURL("image\png");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'EvaluatieForm.aspx',  // page where i have button listenener
        data: '{ data: "' + base64 + '"}',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("inside sucess");
            console.log("result: " + result);
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });

$.post("EvaluatieForm.aspx", { data: base64 }); // another thing i tried
```

C#:

```
var d = Request.Params["data"];
```

The variable d is null when i put a breakpoint at it.
Does anybody see how I can tackle this hurdle, or make it easier?
(note: I do not have a lot of experience with JQuery)

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: variable "d" is null, i would like to have my base 64 data there

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `base64` is? Is it filled but lost in the AJAX request, or is it null from the `toDataURL()` method? Also, why not [convert the canvas to a Blob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata) and send binary `FormData` which you can then bind to the `File` class in C#?

Comment: Although I think Jquery handles it internally, the data you're sending up isn't valid json, it should be like this `'{ "data": "' + base64 + '"}'`

Comment: @George changed it, didn't resolve the issue

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in the sam JQuery u use the base64 to create an <img/> which is filled

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON with base64 could be available as request body.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
{
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace

```
url: 'EvaluatieForm.aspx'
```

by

```
url: 'EvaluatieForm.aspx?data=' + base64
```

and remove

```
data: '{ data: "' + base64 + '"}',
```

then it will work.

Comment: Well wouldn't that need a reload of the url? or something

Comment: @sansactions I don't think so. Just give it a try.

Comment: i will try in half an hour

Comment: I honestly think its somewhere in the way i think that there is a problem

Comment: Are you using `WebMethod` or `PageMethod` or just writing code in page load event?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Just a small change in your existing code, used JSON.stringify to post data.

```
$("#savebtn").bind("click", function () {
 var base64 = $('#sketch')[0].toDataURL("image\png");
var objectToPasss = {data: base64};
var postData =JSON.stringify(objectToPasss );
$.ajax({
  url: 'EvaluatieForm.aspx',  // page where i have button listenener
  data: postData,
  type: 'POST',
  async: true,
  cache: false,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (result) {
     console.log("inside sucess");
     console.log("result: " + result);
  },
  error: function (request, error) {
  // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
     alert('Error!');
   }
 });

$.post("EvaluatieForm.aspx", { data: base64 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#savebtn").bind("click", function () {
 $.ajax({
      url: 'EvaluatieForm.aspx', // page where i have button listenener
      data: {
       sketch: $('#sketch')[0].toDataURL("image\png")
      },
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (result) {
         console.log("inside sucess");
         console.log("result: " + result);
      },
      error: function (request, error) {
      // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
         alert('Error!');
      }
 });
```

where

```
var d = Request.Params["sketch"];
```

The data argument in the jQuery ajax() function works in conjunction with the contentType. As you are setting it to application/json, then it stands to reason that data will be serialized, so setting the sketch variable seems about right.

Answer (score 0):

With ajax you can try xhr.

maybe this thread helps you out! :)

[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)